# element invisible in mobile chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, safari

In this page, the #searchInput element, after a class is applied to it through jQuery, is invisible.

I checked and its visibility is not hidden, its opacity is not 0, and its display is not none.

I know the element is there because when I hover over the code in dev tools, I see its padding, and margins.

[image]

This happens in mobile chrome and safari, but not in desktop chrome and safari.

One can replicate the problem in desktop chrome using chrome dev tools to emulate a mobile device.

Here is how to replicate the problem:

1. Go to this page: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcMlJSU1J4RmZlSXc/KE_home.html
2. Scroll down so that the header is no longer in view
3. Scroll Up, but not enough so that the header is back into view.

The class `.stickySearch` should be applied and it will be fixed and the top of the page in desktop and mobile; but, in mobile, it is invisible.

Here is the JS code that add the class:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st<=lastScrollTop){
        //scroll up
        if($(this).scrollTop()>235) $('#searchInput').removeClass('slideBack').addClass('stickySearch');
        else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').addClass('slideBack');
     }
else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').removeClass('slideBack');
lastScrollTop = st;
```

`.slideBack` has no styling associated with it, buy `.stickySearch` does:

```
.stickySearch{
    width:60% !important;
    position:fixed !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:32px !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:678px){
    .stickySearch{
        width:65% !important;
    }
}
```

This happens on my iPad, Nexus 7, and Galaxy Nexus. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue on desktop with Firefox. Indeed, Chrome doesn't have it, but Firefox 27 has it.

For those who want to see this issue, just hit his URL in Firefox and scroll down and up. As soon as the header comes into view, the damn search input shows for a split of a second then disappears.